# Jinja elif not working even though condition is true

Tags: python, django, jinja2

The fourth elif statement is the one causing me the issue. I have swapped the third elif statement with the fourth and every time the fourth is in third place it works.

```
{% block content%}

{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home_page.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home_w_d_cs.css' %}">


{% if first_hour_d == 'clear sky' and time_of_day == True %} <!-- day == True means day -->

    <div class="side-hour-icon">
        <img src="{% static 'images/sunny-black.png' %}" alt="" width="55" height="50">
    </div>


{% elif first_hour_d == 'clear sky' and time_of_day == False %} <!-- day == False means night -->
    <div class="side-hour-icon">
        <img src="{% static 'images/clear-night-black.png' %}" alt="" width="55" height="50">
    </div>

{% elif first_hour_d == 'overcast clouds' or 'broken clouds' %}
    <div class="side-hour-icon">
        <img src="{% static 'images/cloudy2.png' %}" alt="" width="55" height="50">
    </div>
    
{% elif first_hour_d == 'few clouds' or 'scattered clouds' %}
    <div class="side-hour-icon">
        <img src="{% static 'images/few-clouds-black.png' %}" alt="" width="55" height="50">
    </div>


{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

I want to have a few elif statements, maybe 10 or 12. Is this possible?

Comment: There are really few language that do accept construct like `first_hour_d == 'overcast clouds' or 'broken clouds'`, and here it doesn't do what you think it does. On the other hand, this is a valid construct, doing what you expect: `first_hour_d == 'overcast clouds' or first_hour_d == 'broken clouds'`

Comment: Without reading much, I think you need: `elif a == "a" or a == "aaaa"`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do:

```
{% elif first_hour_d == 'overcast clouds' or 'broken clouds' %}
```

because the second string will always evaluate to `True`.

You must do:

```
{% elif first_hour_d == 'overcast clouds' or first_hour_d == 'broken clouds' %}
```